# Firebase authentication, firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to make a login page to my firebase project, but always when i send the params to the functions its returns "Firebase is not defined . Here's my code:

```
<button id="login" onclick="signIn()"><Login</button>
```

The function signIn() only change the href to http://localhost:5000/signin/:email/:password

then i have this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const adm = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const signin = require('./modules/signin');
const firebase = require("firebase");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
adm.initializeApp(
    functions.config().adm
);

const app = express();

app.get('/signin/:email/:password', (request, response) => {
    exports.signin = signin(request.params.email, request.params.password);    
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

and my function is only

```
function signin (email, password) {
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
    // user signed in
    console.log ("Usuário logado com sucesso!");
    return True;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            // alert('Wrong password.');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert(errorCode+": "+errorMessage); 
            return false;        
        }
    });

}

module.exports = signin;
```

im trying to use the index.js on functions folder as a type of "controller" to call functions on backend, but im having trouble to solve this simple problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the Firebase client SDK in Cloud Functions.  Cloud Functions is considered backend code, and doesn't run on the browser.  If you want to sign in the user, you have to use the SDK in your browser code, not backend code.